# SQLException in contentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, sqlexception

Everybody knows NotePad exaple for android. Its content provider contains "throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);" in the end of insert method, but when I try to use this row in my own contentProvider Eclipse shows an error "Unhandled exception type SQLException".

How can I throw this Exception from this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that this method will throw this exception so add "throws SQLException" to your method header e.g.

```
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) throws SQLException {
    //dostuff
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help. It tells "Exception SQLException is not compatible with throws clause in ContentProvider.insert(Uri, ContentValues)". NotePad example doesn't contain "throws" either

Comment: I just looked at the code. Actually SQLException is a runtime exception. You do not need to declare it at all in the method header. I don't understand your original error msg in Eclipse - it compiles fine for me.

Comment: I don't understand why eclipse doesn't show this msf in NotePad example, but in my app it does

Comment: ok, I see why - You've imported the wrong SQLException. At the top of your src file change import java.sql.SQLException to import android.database.SQLException

Comment: I had same issue in Android studio and after changing import to 

"import android.database.SQLException;" everything worked fine. thanks buddy.